# Solving of basic recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

let us suppose we have following recurrence relation

$T(n)=T(n-1)+1$    where  $T_{0}=1$

we need to find  homogeneous solution and particular solution , for homogeneous solution, we have

$T(n)-T(n-1)=0$
so in index form  $a_n-a_{n-1}=0$
therefore $r-1=0$ , from where  we have  $r=1$   and general solution will be
$a_n=\alpha*r^n$ , because $r=1$ we have  $a_n=\alpha$ 
now for particular solution we have  $f(n)=1$ , that  why simple take particular solution $T_p=A$
if we put  get

$A=A+1$  but how to solve this equation? please help me

Comment: any help  guys?of course i can use iterated version but  i need  to know  how to solve using characteristic equation

Answer (score 1):

The solution to $T(n) = T(n-1) + 1$ is $T(n) = n + T(0)$.
The solution to $T(n) = T(n-1)$ is $T(n) = T(0)$.

Comment: i know but can i find  it using characteristic equation?

Comment: i think  that   there was  a misunderstanding  ,, i have asked about if it is possible to solve this system using characteristic equation , homogeneous and  non homogeneous  techniques